# SSRS - Adding "LIKE" filter criteria to report builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report-builder2.0

I want to add a LIKE filters with wildcards in SSRS report builder. I tried this using contains clause present in filter data section of report builder. I tried both '*' and '%', but of them failed.

I tried 
       MyFieldName contains 2451 - this succeds
       MyFieldName contains 24* - this fails
       MyFieldName contains 24% - this fails

From below link I feel that this is an old problem with no solution till yet.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/202792/ssrs-adding-like-filter-criteria-to-report-builder

What do you guys suggest?

Thanks 
Ravi Gupta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `InStr` function

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!MyFieldName.Value, "2451"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks darren for prompt reply, what I need is 
"=IIF(InStr(Fields!MyFieldName.Value, "2451*"),TRUE,FALSE)" and I get error saying invalid character when I write this.

Comment: Below worked for me 
  IF(FIND(MyFieldName, "24") = 1, TRUE, FALSE)
Got this idea from your answer. Thanks. I'll add this as answer to my own question, but can do so only after 8 hours.

Comment: Seems to me that this doesn't really answer the question since it doesn't handle wildcards.   It's nice that the OP was able to move on with his project, but it doesn't help future users who are looking for a way to use wildcards in an SSRS filter.

Comment: @TabAlleman this answer has been accepted and helped the OP, which was my aim.  If you have a better solution then feel free to post it.

Answer (score 4):

In SSRS we can't use `Like`. Instead of which you can use `Contains`.

```
IIF((MyFieldName).ToString().Contains("RequiredString"),"True","False)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the report builder in Visual studio there is a Like and it works. Use a * as wildcard in your search string

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, Below function worked for me:

> IF(FIND(MyFieldName, "24") = 1, TRUE, FALSE)

This is just a partial answer as this will work for cases like (blabla*), but its not for cases like (bla*bla, blabla*). So anyone having a better idea is most welcome.

Got idea to do this from Darren's comment above.

Thanks 
Ravi Gupta

Answer (score 0):

The Report Builder does not support the `LIKE` operator.  You must use `CONTAINS`;

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late to the party, but I worked out a solution for parameter filters for my dataset.
Adding a filter to my dataset with
**Expression:**

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!AccountName.Value, Parameters!paramAccountName.Value) OR Parameters!paramAccountName.Value = "*", TRUE, FALSE)
```

**Type**

```
Boolean
```

**Operator**

```
=
```

**Value**

```
true
```

The parameter are defaulted to "*" so the report looks like it grabs everything by default.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this old thread and I'm curious why you can't use the like keyword, since I've always used it.
Did you try something like this?
Where (AccountName like '%' + @paramAccountName + '%' or @paramAccountName ='')